# Count on recursive array search has strange behavior

Tags: php, arrays

I need to count how many values ​​there are in a multidimensional array and update the count value.

But I get a strange behavior, as only some values ​​are counted, others are duplicated.

Here the code: 
[phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nb8-sd0)

**EDIT**
Here the code:

```
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key = $key;
        if($needle===$value || (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$region = array('Emilia Romagna', 'Abruzzo', 'Lombardia', 'Emilia Romagna', 'Abruzzo', 'Abruzzo');
$locality = array('Bologna', 'Bolognano', 'Milano', 'Bologna', 'Bologna');
$dataRegion = array();
$dataLocality = array();

foreach ($region as $result) {
    if($key = recursive_array_search($result, $dataRegion)) {
        $dataRegion[$key]['count']++;
    } else {
        $dataRegion[] = array(
            'type'    => 'region',
            'label'   => $result,
            'count'   => 1,
        );
    }
}

foreach ($locality as $result) {
    if($key = recursive_array_search($result, $dataLocality)) {
        $dataLocality[$key]['count']++;
    } else {
        $dataLocality[] = array(
            'type'    => 'locality',
            'label'   => $result,
            'count'   => 1,
        );
    }
}
print_r($dataLocality);
echo '<br/> ==================== <br/>';
print_r($dataRegion);
```

I can not explain exactly why this behavior ..

Comment: You should post the code here.

Comment: `return false;` strange enough there ))

Comment: I find your recursion dubious. What exactly are you aiming with it?

Comment: Also, since your `$region` and `$locality` are flat, one dimensional arrays why aren't you using inbuilt functions as `in_array()`, but prefer to make your life complicated? ;-)

Comment: No, I don't want to complicate my life! ;-) 
The code posted is just a working example of the problem I faced. 
The arrays that I get are very nested and are the results of the database, and then to count the results I used this code.